# Is nested form possible in dynamic forms in angular 2 without using of formbuilder

Tags: angular

nested form is possible in reactive form but I don't know how to implement it in dynamic form in angular 2
so is it possible in dynamic forms in angular 2 ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: a millions of articles out there around Angular2 dynamic form, just google them

Comment: I know how to create dynamic forms but I want to create nested form in dynamic form

Comment: You are maybe looking for formgroups?

Comment: yes, u r right @ Vega

Comment: Hi, we (at work) have been working on that topic and I gave a proper answer you may want to check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55457210/2398593 :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular's (2.x+) approach to nested forms is not similar to AngularJS (1.x).

In Angular, `FormGroup`s and `FormArray`s are already letting you create a nested form.

```
<form [formGroup]="fatherForm">

   <input [formControl]='fatherForm.get('firstName')'>

   <form  [formGroup]="fatherForm.get('childForm')">
       <input [formControl]='fatherForm.get('childForm.aNestedControl')'>
   </form>
</form>
```

And then in the class :

```
fatherForm = new FormGroup({

    firstName : new FormControl()

    childForm: new FormGroup({

        aNestedControl : new FormControl()

    })

})
```

you can even make it cleaner in the html by creating `getter`s:

in the class :

```
   get childForm(){
       return this.fatherForm.get('childForm')

   }
```

and then in the html :

```
<form [formGroup]="fatherForm">

   <input [formControl]='fatherForm.get('firstName')'>

   <form  [formGroup]="childForm">
       <input [formControl]='childForm.get('aNestedControl')'>
   </form>
</form>
```

Comment: I am confused but I will try and confirm

Comment: @Milad I have a problem; on submitting the form, my parent form does not contain the child form's values. If I put a debug point, I can see the child form with all the selected values, but on submission parent form shows empty object. Any idea where the values are getting missed?